# Webview in android opens in new screen occupying Full screen

Tags: android, android-webview

i am trying to open a pdf file in a webview in android using the following code.It works well except that it opens in a new view.i have made a xml file and i want the data to be displayed in a webview and not in a new view.Any help will be appreciated.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        String pdf = "http://commonsware.com/AndTutorials/AndTutorials-3_1-CC.pdf";
        String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf;
        Log.i("TAG", "Opening PDF: " + url);

        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

And this is my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/pdf_top_box" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_pdf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_pdf" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post logcat. there is probably a new activity started, you'll see which in the logcat

Comment: if I was a betting man, I'd say that by attempting to open the PDF in the webview, the webview is broadcasting an intent and whatever your device is using to handle PDF files is then launching a new activity to display the content.